# Start fresh after error handling message

Tags: apex, visualforce, error-messages, try-catch

So I have a validation rule that doesn't allow a user to enter in a "Receiving Quantity" that is greater than the "Open Quantity" custom field. If I have an open quantity of 5, but I enter in 6 as the receiving quantity, it'll throw the error when I hit "Submit" which is good.

The problem is that if I then update the 6 to a 5 and hit submit, it still throws the error. From the debug logs it's because it just adds the 5 making it now 11 which is still greater than the open quantity. How can I go about "resetting" the variable to what they were before the error was thrown?

```
public class ReceivePOLinesController {

private ApexPages.StandardSetController standardController;

public List<Purchase_Order_Line__c> selectedLines {get;set;}

public id poId {get;set;}

public decimal QTY {get;set;}

public ReceivePOLinesController(ApexPages.StandardSetController standardController)
{
    this.standardController = standardController;
    if (!Test.isRunningTest()) standardController.addFields(new String[]{'Purchase_Order__c','Receiving_Quantity__c','Name','Product__c','Order_Quantity__c','Open_Quantity__c','Quantity_Received__c'});

}

public PageReference retreiveLines() 
{
    //Get selected PO lines
    selectedLines = (List<Purchase_Order_Line__c>) standardController.getSelected();

    poId = selectedLines[0].Purchase_Order__c;

    return null;
}

public PageReference receiveLines() 
{   

    for (Purchase_Order_Line__c selectedLine : selectedLines)
    {
        try {
            selectedLine.Quantity_Received__c += selectedLine.Receiving_Quantity__c;
            update selectedLine;
        }

        catch(DMLException de) {
            Apexpages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.SEVERITY.FATAL, de.getDmlMessage(0)));
            return NULL;
        }

        catch(Exception e) {
            Apexpages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.SEVERITY.FATAL, e.getMessage()));
            return NULL;
        }      
    }
    PageReference acctPage = new PageReference ('/' + poId);
    acctPage.setRedirect(true);
    return acctPage;
}
}
```

Visualforce Page:

```
<apex:page lightningStylesheets="true"
       docType="html-5.0"
       standardController="Purchase_Order_Line__c"
       extensions="ReceivePOLinesController"
       recordSetVar="POLines"
       action="{!retreiveLines}">
<apex:pageMessages id="errormsg"/>
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Receive Purchase Order Lines">
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton action="{!Cancel}" value="Cancel"/>
            <apex:commandButton action="{!receiveLines}" value="Submit" reRender="errormsg"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!selectedLines}" var="line">
            <apex:column value="{!line.Name}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!line.Product__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!line.Order_Quantity__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!line.Open_Quantity__c}"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="Receiving Quantity">
                <apex:inputField value="{!line.Receiving_Quantity__c}"/>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable> 
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should query the database to get the actual values before trying to update the record:

```
Map<Id, Purchase_Order_Line__c> currentData = new Map<ID, Purchase_Order_Line__c>([
    SELECT Quantity_Received__c FROM Purchase_Order_Line__c
    WHERE Id = :selectedLines
]);

for (Purchase_Order_Line__c selectedLine : selectedLines)
{
    try {
        Purchase_Order_Line__c current = currentData.get(selectedLine.Id);
        selectedLine.Quantity_Received__c = current.Quantity_Received__c + selectedLine.Receiving_Quantity__c;
        update selectedLine;
    }
```

As an aside, I wouldn't design this logic in the controller. It should be in a trigger so that if the transaction is rolled back, the quantity would not be affected in your Visualforce page.

**NOTE**: This is only meant to be illustrative. You still have other issues in your code, namely, DML in a loop, which can cause excessive governor limit usage. There are a number of other issues you need to fix before you attempt to deploy this to production.

Comment: Wow thank you so much for the feedback! I am pretty clueless to a lot of this stuff still so I appreciate it. I will make the suggested changes to my code before deploying.